# JS - submit more than one form with one button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to submit more than 1 form and decided to do so with JS. (at least the subbmiting part)
so i have this simple form:

```
<form action="test/submit.php" method="post" id="submit_template">
    <center>
        <input type="hidden" id="payment" name="DB_Table" value="payment">
            <div id="template" class="collapse.toggle">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="Full_Name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="Full_Name">
            </div>
    </center>
</form>
```

I created a JS to change the ID for that form id - such as "submit_template1...2..." etc
and the button looks like this:

```
<button id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="button=1" onclick="submitForms()">Submit</button>
```

i tried to create a JS for subbmitting all forms the code looks like this:

```
submitForms = function()
{
    for(i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByTagName("form").length ; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("submit_template" + i).submit();
    }
}
```

when i have more than 1 form it get the following error:
Uncought TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
at submitForms (:106)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

funny thing is that if i go to the F12 console and do something like:
var i = 1
document.getelementbyid("submit_template" + i).id

it works perfectly...

any ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does it redirects to some other or same page?

Comment: Try `i+1` in `document.getElementById("submit_template" + i).submit();`

Comment: @Akshay - Hello Akshay - thank you so much for you quick response!
it appears like since i dont have "submit_template0" it failed and had to set my i value to 1 at first :)
The forms being sent to the a different page (test/submit.php):
<form action="test/submit.php" method="post" id="submit_template">

now it works, but manage to send only 1 form why?

Comment: It sends 1 because you need to `preventDefault()` behaviour of forms

Comment: @CurrentRedemption You probably have to listen for submit events and then use `preventDefault()`, but I am not sure

Comment: @Akshay - Just read about the "preventDefault()" function its disable from redirecting links or others, but that wont solve my issue

Comment: @CurrentRedemption That solution will only work if you are using ajax. Otherwise check Quentin's answer.

Comment: @Akshay - I'm still trying to figure out what he ments and making some readings.

Comment: @CurrentRedemption The better solution will be to combine all your forms into one. But if that is not possible, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yab3dqvp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form the browser makes an HTTP request to the form's `action` and navigates to it.

Under normal circumstances, you can't navigate to multiple pages at the same time: You only have one viewport.

When you try, it cancels the previous form submission.

If you want to navigate to multiple places at the same time then you need multiple viewports. One way to achieve that would be to have an `<iframe>` for each `<form>` and set the `target` attribute in each. That way the the form submission doesn't trigger navigation away from the page the form is on.

Another approach would be to *not* submit the forms at all, but to make all the HTTP requests with JavaScript (e.g. `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`) so there is no navigation at all.

You could also redesign the forms so you have a **single** form that submits all the data in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the thing is that i need to process the data inside that form and create an HTML Table + send all that data into a DB, doesnt iframe whos the output back to the same page?

Comment: No, it puts it in the iframe.

Comment: and then i just submit every single iframe (which holds each form)?

Comment: No. You submit the forms … and while you could put each one in a separate document and load those documents into iframes, my suggestion was to keep you current approach and just add the iframes to it (and then submit all the forms (still in the main page) to different iframes using the target attribute. (This is pretty ugly and the last approach I suggested is probably the best).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u do it like this

```
 for(i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByTagName("form").length ; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[i].submit();
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[i].preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: lol not sure why i didnt thought about that so simple! and pretty much the same :)
but i figured out my problem thanks to Akshay, my problem is now that only 1 form being sent for unknown reason.